# spinner contains languages on menu bar

Tags: android, resources, spinner, multilingual

I want to know how to create a spinner in menu bar that contains the languages English, Malaysia and Chinese

When one of the languages is selected example English the English resources will be activated

if Chinese is selected the Chinese resources will be activated and if Bahasa Malaysia is selected the Malaysia resources will be activated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on ImageView click, write this code,

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"scheduling@epiclanguage.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: do i need to write a new code in Home.java?

Comment: @KelvsRicafort: You need to insert this code on, where you implement ImagView Click.